# Compiling multiple LESS files with different variable values

Tags: wordpress, less

I'm currently creating a site that has multiple color themes - it seemed natural to use LESS and @variables for this (using Wordpress / WP-Less). I soon realized I couldn't find a really clean way have only one, monolithical stylesheet, as, of course, after compiling variables can't be overwritten, and it's unfeasible to compile on every page render.

Creating separate theme stylesheets (which only contain the variable-modified values) seems to be the only way to go, but it will be somewhat cumbersome to maintain in the future.
I'm utilizing only 1-3 variables, but they are referenced many times.

Is it possible to utilize WP-Less/Lessphp to render multiple .css from one .less with several different variables changed?

Or is there a simpler / other standard way to achieve the above?

Comment: why not use http://lesscss.org/#usage the javascript on top of your wordpress instead of a plugin... or i am missing something?

Comment: The site will have relatively large traffic, pre-rendering the stylesheet seemed to be the way to go in terms of performance. Relying on the client to render the css file seemed to be risky (what if JS is disabled, performance on mobile devices, etc.)

Comment: why not use `requirejs` optimization for css great tutorial here http://goo.gl/QZT3w

Answer (score 1):

Less offers a way to modify variables at run-time:

Here's an excerpt from the docs online - http://lesscss.org/:

---

Modify variables

modifyVars enables modification of LESS variables in run-time. When called with new values, the LESS file is recompiled without reloading. Simple basic usage:

less.modifyVars({
    '@buttonFace': '#5B83AD',
    '@buttonText': '#D9EEF2'
});